# Accessing resources for Android UI Automator tests

Tags: java, android, localization, android-uiautomator

I'm working on a set of tests using UI Automator on Android.  I have it working, but my current tests are made with lots of string literals.

The string literals were fine when I was just trying to get things to work in the first place, but they will be bad going forward.  If the app is changed, the string literals will need to be changed to match.  Also, it's stupid that my tests would have to be completely redone to test localized builds in other languages.

The app itself has all strings stored in resources.  Every string has an invariant identifier... here's an example:

```
<string name="more_options">More options</string>
```

The app code will always use the name `more_options` to look up the string resource, rather than hard-coding `"More options"` into the code.

So what I want is to import all the string resources, store them in some kind of map object, and then in my UI Automator test code use something like `m.get("more_options")` rather than a literal string `"More options"` as I do now.

Whatever I do, I want it to just be part of the JAR file that gets built and pushed to the device to run the tests.  I don't want to, for example, push the XML string resource files to the device and try to read them at test runtime.  I want to have the data built in when the JAR file is built.

I looked at the files produced by building the app, and the names like `more_options` are just set to integers.  These must be indexes or pointers into a store of resources, but I'm not sure how I could copy that store into my UI Automator project and get it connected up; in an Android app you use a `Context` object to access resources, and a UI Automator JAR file doesn't have a `Context`.

This has to be a common problem, and people must have solved it already, but my Google searches haven't found any discussions of how people are solving this.

If I don't get any advice, I'm going to write a Python script that imports the XML file and writes a Java file that has a function that builds the map I need, then call that from my UI Automator test programs.  (I have a Python script that runs the sequence of command-line tools to kick of a UI Automator test, anyway... I don't mind making that do more work.)  But I figure there should be a pure-Java solution for this, probably one that involves grabbing the already-compiled files out of the application's source directory.

Comment: It looks when decompiling an app with apk-tool, the strings are represented by their name not their resource id. Maybe check out the [source](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool)

Comment: this kinda worked for me :
`String value = this.getApp().getApplicationContext().getResources().getText(id).toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck up with a similar problem. 
I ended up creating a static hash map in Java for all the string literals.
So I had files for different languages with the same key and their localized values.

Then wrote a module to manipulate the device language at runtime and return the corresponding localized value for a key.

Comment: This is what I did as well.  I wrote a Python program that uses the Python XML library to slurp in all the string resources, then it writes a static `HashMap<String, String>` of the string resources.  I don't think anyone is going to give me a better answer than this one so I'm accepting it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can get context:

```
val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
```

and then in your tests:

```
context.getString(R.string.more_options)
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually target a UI element through a resource ID.  Those are pretty static.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please explain how a `UiAutomator` program can use a resource ID from another APK to access strings within that other APK?  I am not talking about unit tests that are compiled against a given APK ("white box testing"), I am talking about a completely separate program that uses `UiAutomator` to test ("black box testing").  If this is possible it would be a good answer to my question.

Comment: @steveha - I thought about this today, and I noticed that the 'resourceId' API was not added until 4.3 (API 18).  Basically, all the buttons, TextViews, etc should be identifiable through a package/id identifier.  Look at the `UiSelector` class and the `resourceId(String resourceId)` method [in the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#resourceId(java.lang.String).  Use the `uiautomatorviewer` to view these resource IDs.

Comment: Now, this is very interesting.  We aren't on API 18 yet, so I can't use it yet, but this bears watching.